# TeamCity - setting a parameter in build step based on returned value from previously called script

Tags: python, teamcity, robotframework

I have a Python script in a TeamCity build which creates a folder dynamically at build time.

I'd like to return the name within the script to the calling build and reuse this in a later step.

Is it possible to use the TeamCity set parameter and assign it to a variable for re-use?

```
##teamcity[setParameter name='ddd' value='fff']
```

Comment: As you said, it should be possible to use TeamCity service messages to set the parameter. How would you like to reuse the parameter? From another build configuration?

Comment: I'm using it to integrate with tests running in Robot Framework. They'll pick up on the set parameter for the folder, for downloads.

Comment: To clarify - the workflow I'm trying to create. Python script is called in TeamCity build, creating a datetime based folder on agent. Python script returns a string value of folder location/name to Team City. At this point I need to trap this returned value as variable to use on test initialisation, in Robot Framework (to set the corresponding folder for download use)

Answer (score -1):

You can follow https://www.tabsoverspaces.com/233501-passing-data-between-build-steps-in-teamcity. Name the varaible `env.<name>`, you can then read it in next step in Python using `os.environ['<name>']`.

Comment: I'm possibly not doing this correctly, in that case, build reports this: 'os.environ['DLFolder']' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: `os.environ` needs to be called in Python. Outside, i.e. in Bash or PowerShell it's just a regular environment variable.

Comment: So this is setting the os.environ['DLFolder']=/required/path in the script and returning that instead of string, then using the ##teamcity[setParameter name='env.DLFolder' type syntax in Team City?

Comment: Yes. Doing `##teamcity[setParameter` sets the value "in" TeamCity and in next step you can read it from `os.environ`.

Comment: python CreateDownloadsFolder.py     -- returning DLFolder
echo "##teamcity[setParameter name='env.DLFolder' value='DLFolder']"
python -m robot  --variable DLFOLDER:%env.DLFolder%  -- is this the correct flow for passing the variable through Team City?

Comment: @cincura.net please consider subscribing to new tag, https://stackoverflow.com/tags/firebird-.net-provider/info